# Is there something like `helm exec`?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-helm

I use the following `helm` (2.4.2) commands in my `gitlab-ci.yml` script:

```
- helm upgrade --install myapp-db --wait --set postgresUser=postgres,postgresPassword=postgres,postgresDatabase=myapp stable/postgresql
- helm upgrade --install myapp-web ./myapp-chart --wait --set env.DATABASE_URL="${DATABASE_URL}"
```

It's part of a deployment to my staging/review environment. After the above commands complete, I would like to execute commands against the `my-app` pod to create/migrate the database. At the moment this is achieved through the use of an `initContainer` (defined in the referenced yaml file). But I would prefer the logic to be part of the CI script - so I don't have to have a separate deployment file for production.

Is there a way to do this with `helm`? Or is my only option to use `kubectl exec`? If I use `kubectl exec`, is there an easy way to get the name of the pod using `helm`?

Answer (score 0):

This GitHub issue addresses how you might use `kubectl` to find out the name of a pod based on a label:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/8876

I implemented the following:

```
- export POD_NAME=`kubectl get pod -l "app=myapp-web-chart" -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}'`
- kubectl exec $POD_NAME -- mix ecto.migrate
```

Still, it would be much nicer if there was a way to do this with `helm`